# How to make ng-repeat item goTop/goBottom with animation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to use Angular to animate something like the demo below.
When clicking the button, the item should go up, go down, go top or go bottom.
   http://plnkr.co/edit/PbuhAYD2r1TXBcZM8EAl?p=preview,

```
 <div ng-controller="animateCtrl">
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="ulFade" id="autoscroll">
    <li ng-repeat="li in lis" class="fade show">
      {{li.name}}
      <button ng-click="removeItem($index)">x</button>
      <button ng-click="upItem($index)" ng-show="$index>0">up</button>
      <button ng-click="downItem($index)" ng-show="$index<lis.length-1">down</button>
      <button ng-click="goTop($index)">Top</button>
      <button ng-click="goBottom($index)">Bottom</button>
    </li>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="li.name">
      <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The animation of "up" and "down" is ok, but when "top" or "bottom" are clicked, the animation is wrong.

How can I move the clicked item when I click "goTop" and "goBottom"?

Comment: Can't able to get your question can you please make it clear

Comment: I mean how to change the position of ng-repeat item?And can show the moving process dynamically.Maybe you can see the demo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the element that has to go to top/bottom, you should just move it one element after the other. Have a look at the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5DGcAP5kmFDfKrS5ogyA?p=preview).

I used recursion and called the same `scope.goTop` function again after a short timeout (`$timeout` to rerender the HTML) of 520ms until the top of the list is reached. Therefore, you can just call `scope.goUp` that does the moving job for you.

Comment: Thanks u so much, it helps me a lot!!!!!
However, I have another prolem,how can i control z-index of the clicked item,as u see the item goes up  are always behind the others.
 I haved tried many times to set z-index,but nothing changed.

Comment: what do you want to do with the items? shall they appear behind or infront of the other elements?

Comment: the clicked item should appear infront of others no matter go up/down
Now just  the item go down/bottom appear right,but when the item go up/top, it appears behind the others.